# Lua issue with cos?

Tags: lua

I have rewritten my previous code on the forums to something much nicer,this is made for TI-Nspire Calculator's,it will solve for all the missing sides and angles of a triangle and then draw the triangle on the right with the supplied measures or sides/angles.I have an issue with the solution finder,when I input data into the fields of A,B,C,a,b,c it won't calculate any missing side or the area/perimeter.I can click enter and it won't crash or solve for anything.If I fill all fields however,I get en error with my if statments and before that an error with my cos^1.Heres the code

```
platform.apilevel = '2.3'     
A,B,C,a,b,c,Perimeter,Area=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
values = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} 
selection=1

function on.arrowKey(key)
if key=="up" then
    selection=selection-(selection>1 and 1 or -7)
elseif key=="down" then
    selection=selection%8+1     
end
platform.window:invalidate()
end

function on.paint(gc)
gc:setColorRGB(0,0,0)
gc:fillRect(0,0,318,212)
gc:setFont("sansserif", "r", 12)
gc:setColorRGB(0,200,0)
gc:drawString("Welcome Right Triangle Solver V:1",37,-2)
gc:setColorRGB(200,0,0)
gc:setFont("sansserif","i",6)
gc:drawString("Created by: ApprenticeCoder And Ldstudios Of tifreakware.net",30,16)
gc:setFont("sansserif","b",12)
gc:drawString("Only Click",16,160)
gc:drawString("Enter Once!",10,180)
gc:drawRect(6,160,98,44)
gc:drawRect(5,32,100,125)
gc:drawRect(151,32,165,178)
gc:drawRect(151,45,165,165)  
gc:setFont("sansserif","i",6)
gc:drawString("Section For Drawing Triangle",173,32)
gc:setColorRGB(200,0,0)

for i,v in ipairs({"A","B","C","a","b","c","Perimeter","Area"}) do
    gc:setFont("serif","r",12)
    if selection==i then
        gc:setFont("serif","b",12)
    end
    gc:drawString(v..": "..values[i],10,15+15*i) 
end
end

function on.charIn(char) 
if char:find("%d") then 
    values[selection]=tonumber(values[selection]..char)
    platform.window:invalidate()
end
end

function on.backspaceKey()
values[selection]=string.sub(tostring(values[selection]),0,-2)
if values[selection]:find("%d") then
    values[selection]=tonumber(values[selection])
else
    values[selection]=0
end
platform.window:invalidate()
end
function on.enterKey()
if values[A]==0 and values[B]~=0 and values[C]~=0 and values[a]~=0 then
values[A]=math.sqrt(values[B]^2+values[C]^2-((2*values[B]*values[C])*math.cos(values[a])))
elseif values[B]==0 and values[A]~=0 and values[C]~=0 and values[b]~=0 then
values[B]=math.sqrt(values[A]^2+values[C]^2-((2*values[A]*values[C])*math.cos(values[b])))
elseif values[C]~=0 and values[A]~=0 and values[B]~=0 and values[c]~=0 then
values[C]=math.sqrt(values[A]^2+values[B]^2-((2*values[A]*values[B])*math.cos(values[c])))
end
if values[a]==0 and values[A]~=0 and values[B]~=0 and values[C]~=0 then
values[a]=(math.cos^-1)((values[B]^2+values[C]^2-values[A]^2)/(2*values[B]*values[C]))
elseif values[b]==0 and values[A]~=0 and values[B]~=0 and values[C]~=0 then
values[b]=(math.cos^-1)((values[A]^2+values[C]^2-values[B]^2)/(2*values[A]*values[C]))
elseif values[c]==0 and values[A]~=0 and values[B]~=0 and values[C]~=0 then
values[c]=(math.cos^-1)((values[A]^2+values[B]^2-values[C]^2)/(2*values[A]*values[B]))
end
if values[Perimeter]==0 and values[A]~=0 and values[B]~=0 and values[C]~= 0 then
values[Perimeter]=values[A]+values[B]+values[C]
end
if values[Area]==0 and values[A]~=0 and values[B]~=0 and values[C]~=0 then
s=((values[A]+values[B]+values[C])/2)
values[Area]=math.sqrt(s*(s-values[A])(s-values[B])(s-values[C]))
end

platform.window:invalidate()
end
```

Comment: I don't see any code that does any sort of calculation in your example.

Comment: My mistake,I cut out the code to test the rest of my code,it's all up now.

Comment: `math.cos^-1` That's not valid. What is "a function to the power of -1"?

Comment: What about math.cos()^1?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the law of cosines. In this case, you want `math.acos` instead of `math.cos^-1`.